# How to make a map work inside a scrollview in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a scrollview where I have a listview and also a map underneath. When I try to scroll/work with the listview it works fine but if I try to zoom in/drag my finger on the map sideways it doesn't let me but instead it starts to scroll a bit.

How would I successfully adjust this problem so a map in a scrollview would work for xamarin.forms.android? Do I need to create a custom renderer map? If so I have that prepared already for xam.form.android, but what has to be added on top of that? (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin/Droid/CustomMapRenderer.cs)

This is my scrollview code:

```
<ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 1.0, 1, 0.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView x:Name="listview" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="100"  BackgroundColor = "Transparent" SeparatorColor = "Black">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ViewCell >

                            <ViewCell.View>

                                <AbsoluteLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
                                </AbsoluteLayout>

                            </ViewCell.View>

                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView> 


            <maps:Map HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" HeightRequest = "300" x:Name="map" IsShowingUser="false" MapType="Hybrid" />

      </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Multiple scrollers (Listview and the map) inside of a ScrollView is asking for problems. Personally I would re-think the design.

Comment: @SushiHangover I agree 100%. The problem is that this is the design they kinda demand (since their iOS-app has this exact design). It's supertricky though I can imagine.

Comment: Lol, been there, the client is always right ;-) Can you get your hands on the iOS code? I would *assume* that they are using a UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate and handling the ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously to allow a single pan to handle scrolling on multiple views....

Comment: @SushiHangover I do not have that code :/ What I however found was this: https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/db2b721c37f4066da25c I am trying to integrate it now as we speak.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez hey, did you solve this issue? If positive, could you answer your question here with the right solution?